# How to access parent scope inside Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get a variable above the current scope in a Javascript object?

```
var object = {
        access: [{
            actionName: "Defending",
            action: function(unit) {

            }
        }, {
            actionName: "Mining",
            action: function(unit) {
                super.promises.push($interval(function() { // Here I need to access the variable 'promises' from the above scope
                    // do something
                }, 1000));
            }
        }, {
            actionName: "Cutting wood",
            action: function(unit) {
                super.promises.push($interval(function() { // Same here
                    // do something
                }, 1000));
            }
        }],
        promises: []
    };
```

Comment: You can't (easily) traverse (and maybe not at all) but you can simply use `object.promises`

Comment: You would need to use a tree data structure which explicitly tracked the parents of each node. Except for the DOM (which would probably be inappropriate overkill in this case), nothing like you're looking for is provided out-of-the-box in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
var object = {
    access: [{
        actionName: "Defending",
        action: function(unit) {

        }
    }, {
        actionName: "Mining",
        action: function(unit) {
            object.promises.push($interval(function() { // Here I need to access the variable promise from the above scope
                // do something
            }, 1000));
        }
    }, {
        actionName: "Cutting wood",
        action: function(unit) {
            object.promises.push($interval(function() { // Same here
                // do something
            }, 1000));
        }
    }],
    promises: []
};
```